# Get next item from array instead of randomly

Tags: php

My current code gets a name ($recname) from the array ($recnameslist) randomly, I wish to cycle through the names instead, when the last name is reached the first name should be returned and so on, do I use php "next"?  The array changes in size occasionally , i.e. letters are added and removed sometimes.  This is php in a functions.php file in wordpress, so gets called a few times a day.

```
$recnameslist = array ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h' );

$rand_keys = array_rand($recnameslist, 1);

$recname = $recnameslist[$rand_keys] . "\n";
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Should the name change every page load? Is the cycle kept for each individual user, or is every user's page load supposed to move this cycle forward? How are you planning on keeping track of which name should be displayed?

Comment: Yes, with the current code, a new (random) name/letter gets pulled every time the function is called.  The function displays a text message in an email, so no user issues.  The current code pulls a name randomly, instead the code needs to pull a name sequentially, no need to keep track once the email has been sent. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

For getting the next item in the array, you can use `$nextItem = next($recnameslist);`

Read more about it at http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php

Addendum:

I am adding this extra explanation since it appear that nobody wants to read the documentation.

As the original question asked, the next item in the array is retrieved using `next($recnameslist)`.

If you which to start at the beginning of the array, as shown in the documentation, you can use something similar to the following example:

```php
$transport = array('foot', 'bike', 'car', 'plane');
$mode = current($transport); // $mode = 'foot';
$mode = next($transport);    // $mode = 'bike';
$mode = next($transport);    // $mode = 'car';
$mode = prev($transport);    // $mode = 'bike';
$mode = end($transport);     // $mode = 'plane';
```

It's important to note that it is also possible to simply iterate through the array using a for() loop or any other looping mechanism provided by PHP.

Comment: I tried that code, it just returns the 2nd item in the array each time.  So that means  the code needs to store the last name returned, so the next time it is called it gets the next one.